# Can I load a UICollectionView's data in ViewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, viewdidload

My app's startup screen is a collection view.  If the users choose, he/she can "lock" the app using Face ID/Touch ID at app launch.  I do this by presenting a view controller that contains a `UIVisualEffectView` on top of my collection view controller. I screenshot my collection view controller in `viewDidLoad`, then put the screenshot in a `UIImageView` beneath the `UIVisualEffectView`.

The problem is, the collection view is not loaded when the screenshot is taken and the `UIVisualEffectView` controller appears. The screenshot contains the navigation bar, but the content of the view is just black.  I call the function to display the visual effect view controller in the collection view's `viewDidLoad` function.

Is there a way to load the collection view's data before I take a screenshot in `viewDidLoad`? The data is stored in Core Data.  I have already tried moving the Core Data functions from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidLoad`, but that also didn't work.

EDIT: I was able to solve my problem, but not by loading my `UICollectionView`'s data in ViewDidLoad, as that seems to be impossible.  I added a `UIVisualEffectView` directly on top of my `UICollectionView`.  I also added it as a subview to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` so that it would appear above the navigation bar.  The edited code is down below.

Here is my code:

For the collection view controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import LocalAuthentication

var ssImage: UIImage?

class AlbumViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
@IBOutlet weak var albumCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var albums: [NSManagedObject] = []

// MARK: - Actions

func getScreenShot()-> UIImage? {

    var screenshotImage :UIImage?
    let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
    layer.render(in:context)
    screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    ssImage = screenshotImage
    print("Got screenshot.")
    return screenshotImage
}

// ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //Core Date functions
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Album")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "albumName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        albums = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    //Setup
    self.albumCollectionView.reloadData()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if AppSettings.requiresLogin == true {

        getScreenShot()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "authenticateVC") as! LockedLaunchVC
        self.present(rootController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}

//Core Data functions
func save(name: String) {
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Album",
                                   in: managedContext)!
    let albumName = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                    insertInto: managedContext)
    albumName.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "albumName")
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        albums.append(albumName)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
}

//Collection View functions
extension AlbumViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return albums.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = "AlbumCell"
    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AlbumsViewCell
    //Core Data methods
    let albumName = albums[indexPath.row]
    cell.albumNameLabel?.text = albumName.value(forKeyPath: "albumName") as? String
    //Return the finished cell
    return cell
}
}
```

For the UIVisualEffectView controller:

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

class LockedLaunchVC: UIViewController {

    let bioIDAuth = BiometricIDAuth()

    @IBOutlet weak var screenshotImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func unlockButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        authAndDismiss()
    }

    func authAndDismiss(){
        bioIDAuth.authenticateUser() {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Locked VC dismissed.")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        screenshotImageView.image = ssImage
    }
}
```

EDIT: Revised code for my collection view controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AlbumViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
@IBOutlet weak var albumCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var lockedBlurView: UIVisualEffectView!
@IBOutlet weak var lockedLabelView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var lockedLabel: UILabel!

var albums: [NSManagedObject] = []

let bioIDAuth = BiometricIDAuth()

// MARK: - Actions

@IBAction func unwindToAlbumsScreen(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

@IBAction func unlockButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    bioIDAuth.authenticateUser() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {self.lockedBlurView.alpha = 0})
    }

}

// ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //Core Date functions
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Album")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "albumName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        albums = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    //Setup to do when the view will appear
    self.albumCollectionView.reloadData()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    lockedLabelView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    switch bioIDAuth.biometricType() {
    case .faceID:
        lockedLabel.text = "Albums are locked.  Tap anywhere to use Face ID to unlock."
    case .touchID:
        lockedLabel.text = "Albums are locked.  Tap anywhere to use Touch ID to unlock."
    default:
        lockedLabel.text = "Albums are locked.  Tap anywhere to use your passcode to unlock."
    }

    if AppSettings.requiresLogin == false {
        lockedBlurView.alpha = 0
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if AppSettings.requiresLogin == true {
        let curWin = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        curWin?.addSubview(lockedBlurView)
    }
}

//Core Data functions
func save(name: String) {
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Album",
                                   in: managedContext)!
    let albumName = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                    insertInto: managedContext)
    albumName.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "albumName")
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        albums.append(albumName)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
}

//Collection View functions
extension AlbumViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return albums.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = "AlbumCell"
    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AlbumsViewCell
    //Core Data methods
    let albumName = albums[indexPath.row]
    cell.albumNameLabel?.text = albumName.value(forKeyPath: "albumName") as? String
    //Return the finished cell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let albumNameFromCell = albums[indexPath.row]
    albumNameTapped = albumNameFromCell.value(forKeyPath: "albumName") as! String
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "albumCellTappedSegue", sender: self)
}
}
```

Comment: You really can't get a screenshot until `viewDidAppear` is called.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh.  So is there a way to do what I am trying to do?  Or would I need to redesign my login screen so it doesn't have a screenshot?

Comment: Since you don't want the user to be able to see any data while the login screen is visible, there's little reason to get a screenshot of the data.

Comment: @rmaddy I was blurring the screenshot with a visual effect view and using a cross dissolve modal transition style so that the visual effect view looked like it was placed directly on top of the collection view.  So a redesign of my login screen is necessary?

Comment: I might be wrong but your snapshot is black because I believe you do need to have your view on the actual screen for the snapshot to be taken properly at runtime. have you considered adding a UIView on top of your collection that has a clear background and adding effects on top of that?

Comment: @AaronHalvorsen I hadn’t, but that’s genius! I’ll try it now.

Comment: @AaronHalvorsen My only issue is I can't get a view to cover the navigation bar.  Maybe I should just disable the buttons on the navigation bar when the view is visible?

Comment: @AaronHalvorsen I was able to present the view on top of the navigation bar.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't load any view's content in `viewDidLoad`.  According to the Apple View Controller Programming Guide, "`viewDidLoad` is called when the view controller’s content view (the top of its view hierarchy) is created and loaded from a storyboard."  Basically, it's called when the view controller and its subviews are loaded, but not visible.  `ViewDidAppear` is where the view controller and its subviews are made visible.  According to the Apple View Controller Programming Guide, "`viewDidAppear` is called just after the view controller’s content view has been added to the app’s view hierarchy."  In other words, the view controller and its subviews have been made visible.

I was able to solve my problem, although the answer to it doesn't answer this question.  I added the answer to that problem as an edit to my question.